# How to turn Mongo Shell script into Java using MongoTemplate?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate, mongorepository

My Mongo Shell Script:

```js
db.getCollection('order').aggregate([
  { $match: { clientId: "test@gmail.com" } },
  { $lookup: { from: 'ordereddevice', localField: 'id', foreignField: 'order', as: 'orderedDevices' } }
])
```

What I'm using is like this:

```java
MongoClientURI connectionString = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017");
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("db_name");
MongoCollection < Document > collection = database.getCollection("order");
List < Document > pipeline = Arrays.asList(new Document().append("$match", new Document().append("clientId", "test@gmail.com")), new Document().append("$lookup", new Document().append("from", "ordereddevice").append("localField", "id").append("foreignField", "order").append("as", "orderedDevices")));
Block < Document > printBlock = new Block < Document > () {
    @Override public void apply(final Document document) {
        System.out.println(document.get("_id"));
    }
};
collection.aggregate(pipeline).forEach(printBlock);
```

But it will reconnect MongoDB, So I'm looking for a way to use MongoTemplate to do it

Comment: Here is the reference documentation with examples for using [mongoTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation). Please post any specific question you have. Are you just trying to use `mongoTemplate` _or_ is there a specific issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the document, just Finish it myself! lol

```java
    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<OrderedDeviceByOrderId> findOrderedDeviceByOrderId(String clientid) {
        AggregationOperation lookup = Aggregation.lookup("ordereddevice","_id","order","Devices");
        AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("clientId").is(clientid));
        Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, lookup);

        AggregationResults<OrderedDeviceByOrderId> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "order", OrderedDeviceByOrderId.class);
        List<OrderedDeviceByOrderId> orderedDeviceByOrderId = results.getMappedResults();

        orderedDeviceByOrderId.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
        return orderedDeviceByOrderId;
    }
```